# CoreData+RestKit keep local entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data, synchronization, restkit

I am writing a iOS app that uses CoreData+RestKit. I have a problem that local unsynchronized entities are invalidated when I sync from server. I am using RestKit 0.10.1

**The scenario:**
Sync data from server. Add an entry locally (this isn't synchronized with server). Sync data from server.

**Result:**
The local entity is kept out of the object graph. (I can still see it in the db, it's just not connected)

**JSON**

```
{
  ThreadId: 322,
  ThreadMessages: 
  [    
    {
      Text: "Hello Joe",
      AuthorId: 635236,
      AuthorName: "Trudy",
      Timestamp: "2012-06-09T15:42:45.757",
      ThreadMessageId: 546,
      ThreadId: 322
    }
  ]
}
```

**Mapping**

```
threadMessageMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ThreadMessage class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
threadMessageMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"threadMessageId";    
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"ThreadMessageId" toAttribute:@"threadMessageId"];
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"ThreadId" toAttribute:@"threadId"];
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"Text" toAttribute:@"text"];
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"AuthorId" toAttribute:@"authorId"];
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"AuthorName" toAttribute:@"authorName"];
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"Timestamp" toAttribute:@"timestamp"];


threadMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Thread class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
threadMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"threadId";
threadMapping mapKeyPath:@"ThreadId" toAttribute:@"threadId"];
[threadMapping mapKeyPath:@"ThreadMessages" toRelationship:@"threadMessages" withMapping:ThreadMessageMapping];
```

**Details:**
I can use the above mapping in my App fine. I can also insert a new ThreadMessage locally that works fine (it has a threadMessageId of 0). The problem arises when I sync from server and Restkit/CoreData discovers my new item. I doesn't stay in my object graph. Investigating the sqlite db I discovered that it was because the `ZTHREAD` link in the `ZTHREADMESSAGE` table was being nilled.

Is there a way to get RestKit to leave the items that doesn't come from the server alone?

I have also tried to use the connectRelationship to hydrate the connection, but it seems that with my json it isn't feasible

This line causes the `ZTHREAD` column in the `ZTHREADMESSAGES` to go blank for all entities

```
[threadMapping connectRelationship:@"threadMessages" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"threadId"];
```

If I map the inverse relationsip the `ZTHREAD` column is fine, but a new local item still gets dropped from the object graph when resyncing.

```
[threadMessageMapping mapKeyPath:@"ThreadMessageId" toAttribute:@"threadMessageId"];
[threadMessageMapping mapRelationship:@"thread" withMapping:threadMapping];
[threadMessageMapping connectRelationship:@"thread" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"threadMessageId"];
```

I have been unable to figure out where RestKit invalidates my new ThreadMessage. I think it is somewhere in the `RKObjectMappingOperation` but I can't see where the magic happens. I can only see that the ThreadMessage.ThreadId gets nill'ed after the second synchronization.

Comment: Not sure if it is useful, but have you tried using the setNilForMissingRelationships property?

Comment: No - But setting it to NO did not help. The funny thing is, if I set the inverse thread relationship on threadMessage to non-optional in the Model, Core-Data can't save the data. But I still can't figure out why RestKit wants to nil the relationship.

Comment: You don't have a message on the server with an id of 0, and no thread set? If you do it will map to your local object incorrectly because they have the same PK. Or, if you mapping fails somehow and your PK returns 0 the same situation can occur.

Comment: No - It is essentially the JSON I above that I receive when I GET data. RestKit wants to nil the ZTHREAD that is in the database. I guess because it isn't in the dataset from the server. But I would like to keep it!